# google compute vm instance startup script only run during VM launch?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Would be interested is it possible to configure a configuration script in Google Compute which runs only during launching a VM instance and not during reboot?

Currently I see only a `startup script` functionality which could be used installing software during VM creation time, but this scripts runs also when the instance boots or restarts.

I would like something similar to `User Data` using `AWS` where you can specify  configuration script during launch, but this script is not started during restarts.

Is this possible with Google Compute VM instance?

Comment: Can't see it in the docs. Perhaps you can try adding a line to the end of the startup script, `gcloud compute instances remove-metadata vm-name --zone vm-zone --keys startup-script`? I know it's not ideal...

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at this time.

Their new  ContainerOS ships with cloud init and that supports "first boot" scripts, but as far as I know that's the only image they offer with cloud init.